# PDO says it updates the table, but it actually doesn't

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to use a form to update a sql table by first getting its data (editrower.php) and setting that as values in the form, then using the form to update the table (update_contactrequest.php) but it returns saying the rower was updated yet the table does not update.

editrower.php

```
<?php
require('login.php');
?>
        <?php
        include 'php/mysql_connect.php';
        if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $q = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM rowercontacts WHERE id=:id LIMIT 1');
        $q->execute(array(':id'=>$_GET['id']));
        $row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($row){
        echo '
      <form method="post" action="php/update_contactrequest.php"><div class="col-xs-9 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="'.$_GET['id'].'">
          <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
          <input type"text" class="form-control" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" value="'.$row['firstname'].'" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" value="'.$row['lastname'].'" />
        </div>

        <br><br>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Update" />
      </div></form>
        ';
      }
      else{
      echo 'No rower found';
      }
      }
      else{
        echo 'No rower found';
      }
      ?>
```

update_contactrequest.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['loggedIn'] == true){

$rower_id= $_POST['id'];
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
  // connection to the database
try {
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=home','username','password');
} catch(Exception $e) {
exit('Unable to connect to database.');
}

// insert the records
$sql = "UPDATE rowercontacts SET firstname=:firstname, lastname=:lastname WHERE id=:rower_id";
$q = $bdd->prepare($sql);
if($q->execute(array(':firstname'=>$firstname, ':lastname'=>$lastname, ':rower_id'=>$id))){
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Rower Updated.");location.href="../rowerlist.php";</script>';
}
else{
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Something went wrong...");location.href="../rowerlist.php";</script>';
}

}
?>
```

Comment: Stick your prepare and execute in a try/catch and see if it spits anything out. `try { ... } catch (PDOException $err) { echo $err }`

Comment: `execute` returns true if the execution was successful. That doesn't have to mean that any rows where changed.

Comment: It doesn't catch any PDOExceptions.

Comment: Have from your question, not relevant parts removed. And now you can see the error at one glance. In most cases, if you make the code easier to read the rules here on "stack overflow" to fulfill, then stand out the error you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `$q->rowCount()`. Prepared statements will return the number of affected rows.

If the query itself is error free and executes fine, you need the affected rows.

```
$q = $bdd->prepare($sql);
if($q->execute(array(':firstname'=>$firstname, '...'))){
  $updRows = $q->rowCount();
  if($updRows==0){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Affected Rows = 0 !!!");location.href="../rowerlist.php";</script>';
  }
   else{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Rows affected : '.$updRows.'");location.href="../rowerlist.php";</script>';
  }
}
else{
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Something went wrong...");location.href="../rowerlist.php";</script>';
}
```

---

- Over 70% of update queries with 0 affected rows are due to an incorrect `WHERE` the rest comes from the attempt to replace a `record` with `exactly the same values` that already exist.
- The first thing I do in such a case, I let my query as readable text display.
  With [$q->debugDumpParams();](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php) you get that query array.
- `WHERE id = null` is usually not what anyone expected.

---

To your problem **I'm sure you can find the wrong part yourself** in following 3 lines . :-)

```
$rower_id= $_POST['id'];
....
$sql = "UPDATE rowercontacts ... WHERE id=:rower_id";
if($q->execute(array(':firstname'=>$firstname,...,':rower_id'=>$id)))
```

Comment: It tells me 0 affected rows. What does this mean?

Comment: @xSpartanCx : look at my answer at the bottom . (do a refresh to see)

Comment: Wow, I always miss stuff like that. Thanks for the help :)